# How to merge multiple bibliographies from multiple word files

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013, microsoft-word-2011

I'm working with Microsoft Word 2011 for Mac. I have a couple of Word files. Each of them has its own bibliographies. I have to merge all documents into one. To combine the files into one I imported the documents as "objects" into a new document.

How can I merge all of the bibliographies into one?

I have already checked http://blogs.office.com/2010/09/29/move-bibliography-sources/ . I don't see how to accomplish the same with Microsoft Word 2011 for Mac. It does not have the browse option.

Answer (score 1):

I found the way to do it. If you are MAC you will not find what this solution talks about http://blogs.office.com/2010/09/29/move-bibliography-sources/.

For solving the issue, I create a new bibliography. Then Citations - Manage - Citation Source Manager. You will see a Master List and a Current List. I copied all Master List to the Current List. After that, if you update the bibliography you will see all.

Hope this is useful for someone else too.

Answer (score 0):

Say, you have two XML bibliography files containing different references and you want to merge both to make one big master bibliography file. Call one XML file source file and other destination.

- Open both files in an XML editor (note doesn't work, you can install XML editor from download.com).
- After opening XML files, notice that each reference starts with "b:Source" and ends with "<\b:Source>".
- Keeping that starting and ending of each reference in mind, copy all references from source files and paste in destination file.
- Save destination file with a different name, say "merged.xml".
- Browse "merged.xml" from Word by clicking on Manage Sources>Browse>"merged.xml" and you will be able to use all references from one master file.

[image]

Comment: Actually, just cut-pasting into a new document plus working with the citation source manager (making sure everything from the master was added to the current document) worked --- but only if I did NOT update all the citations....